# What is redstone for?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I mine I either find redstone, coal or iron. I understand coal and iron but what is the purpose of redstone?

Comment: minecraft is very open ended, you may or not may not need things that need redstone however that doesn't mean to say it has no purpose and a lot of people to use redstone because it's needed for compasses which in turn is needed for maps, also watches help people mine deep underground and know when it's now daytime for them to come up and keep surfice materials, you may want to read up on the Wiki people keep adding in their answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redstone is used for several items such as compasses (surround a redstone with iron) and watches (surround a redstone with gold) and an ingredient in extending the length in potions.

More importantly, it is used to make redstone wire when placed on the ground. This can transfer the energy produced by, for example, a lever to a door several metres away. This is only the simplest use for it- more complex uses include traps, automatic reed farms, locks and even a simple calculator.

For more information, check the wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone